# Unable to instantiate the UIApplication subclass instance. No class named %@ is loaded."

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, emulation

I am making a simple login setup where username and password is checked and if its true I direct them to the new page. But I get this error... Can some please explain to me what does this kind of error means.

Following is the function in my ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender 
{

    NSString *username = [_userName text];
    NSString *pass = [_password text];

    if ([username isEqualToString:@"admin"] && [pass isEqualToString:@"password"] ) {
         MiddleViewController *middle = [[MiddleViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentedViewController:middle animated:YES completion:nil];
   }
}
```

[image]

MiddleViewController is a subclass UIViewController on the storyboard. 
Then the emulator just goes dark when I press button with admin and password in the field.

Comment: Please check if Xcode is referring to the correct info.plist file. Check in your target's build settings.

Comment: you need to navigate right?

Comment: huge tip:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/65636899/294884

Answer (score 0):

In your main.m there is a main method.

Mine looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

The last parameter in that message is a string representing which class refers to the application's delegate. For you this string is either nil, or is returning nil. I have a feeling you have the literal string `"%@"` there.

Comment: I check the value of all the strings and the middle view. None of them is null. There is no error till the last statement, After that the memory goes all the way up and the screen goes blank. For some reason the view is not initiated

Answer (score -2):

You should instantiate view controller from storyboard (or with nib). Otherwise you get view controller with empty view.